# How can I use Firebase Emulators to test my React App using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jestjs, firebase-storage

I'm trying to use the FirebaseEmulator to test my react components that use Firebase RealtimeDatabase and Firebase Storage.

App.tsx

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/storage'
import { STORAGE_ROOT } from "../../../../Work/hazy-webapp/src/model/storage/storage";
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export default ()=>{

  const [url, setUrl] = useState<null | string>(null)
  
  const storageRef = firebase
    .storage()
    .ref('path/file').getDownloadURL().then((v)=>{
      setUrl(v);
    })

  return <div>
    {url}
  </div>
}
```

And here's my test:

App.test.tsx:

```
import {initializeTestApp, useEmulators} from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing'
import App from '../App'

useEmulators({
  storage:{
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9199
  }
})

initializeTestApp({
  storageBucket: "my-bucket",
  auth: { uid: "alice" }
})

describe('test', ()=>{
  it('can match snapshot', () => {
    const { baseElement } = render(
        <App/>
    );
    expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
  })
})
```

I'm constantly getting 'Uncaught [FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()'

Am I doing this right? thank you